# Steps to get angular 2 universal starter to deploy to an external server host (Google Cloud, Azure, etc)?

Tags: express, angular, webpack, web-deployment, angular-universal

I cloned universal-starter (webpack version) and have it up and running on my local machine using `npm start` and `npm run watch` per the instructions

Now stuck after `npm run build` and attempting to deploy to Azure (and Google Cloud) via the github integration - can't figure out how to set up either to work.

Anyone have a recipe on how to get the webpack bundled files to fire up on an external host with express.js?  Do I need to run commands via a CI integration?  The files in `/dist` don't seem to stand on their own.

Comment: Update: I did manage to use the 1-click Heroku deploy to get this working. haven't figured out how to get the server to do all the webpack goodness of tree shaking, minification, etc for the production app

Comment: Note: This has changed dramatically since Angular 2. While I'm now moved on to SSR, docker, and all kinds of other things, the simplest answer was to move ng build --prod files to a static web host (like s3) and serve them up there (take a look at redirect requirements for index.html) and then push through nginx or cloudfront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This has changed dramatically since Angular 2. While I'm now moved on to SSR, docker, and all kinds of other things, the simplest answer was to

1) Production build
`ng build --prod`

2) Transfer files to a static web host (i.e., I used awscli to connect to a s3 bucket when it was just a static site...I know use SSR so I need to use a node server like express)

3) Serve files (there are some complexities for redirect requirements for index.html for error and for 404...and of course setting the status for both redirects to 200)

4) Put something on the frontend for performance/ ssl/ etc. nginx or a CDN would make sense.

Comment: Can you post your dockerfile? I'm struggling with SSR.

Answer (score 0):

At Netlify you can connect your git repo and tell them what build commands you want them to use. If you specify the "dist" directory, then they will deploy anything that gets in there (after they have compiled your application).

Edit: the lowest tier is free.
Edit2: I am not associated with Netlify. I just used them in my latest deploy, and found the process extremely easy.

Comment: I think you're supposed to add a note whether you're associated with Netlify or not.

Comment: Thanks, made an edit now. I'm not associated with them at all.